# osx server folders being deleted/removed

Tags: mac-osx-server, directory, deleting

I am running a Mac mini as a server for our office.

Files and folders start disappearing from our work folder at random intervals but specifically from one folder.
The work is all stored on an external HDD which I mirrored to another drive and replaced as the drive was constantly giving disk error warnings and I suspected that this may be causing the issue.

I am running osx server and smbup on a mixed windows/mac network.

Does anyone have any advice or pointers as to what the issue may be?
Is there anyway that I could log which program or device is causing this to happen?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: I'd be tempted to enable access logs for AFP (if that is what you are running as your service: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200217 then you can see if files are being deleted by clients. I'd rule that one out. Other than that, without knowing how your Ext. HD is connected and other information, it's hard to say. I've had an issue with bad RAM affecting the HFS+ Journal before causing files to miraculously 'disappear'.

Comment: The external drives are both powered 3TB drives, originally I was considering I got a bad batch but now it seems otherwise (the drives are different brands bought at different times). The server is running mavericks and server 3.2.1 If theres other information I can provide please let me know. Would reseating the ram be an idea to test?